# How to change a Gridview's text colour according to the ErrorMessage() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, colors

I have these codes
 in my cs file:

```
   //A method to display errors in the gridview
    private string ErrorMessage(string input)

        {
            {
                //if there are null values, error message will be displayed.
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                    return input;

            }
            return  "No value entered";// I am supposed to change this to red colour


        }

    public System.Drawing.Color InStockColor(string inStock)
    {
        return System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    } 




 // to read all lines of the posted csv file and put the lines in the grid view
        var data = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath(FilePath))
            // to split the lines according to commas
          .Select(line => line.Split(','))

          .Select(columns => new { A = ErrorMessage(columns[0]), B = ErrorMessage(columns[1]), C = ErrorMessage(columns[2]), D = ErrorMessage(columns[3]), E = ErrorMessage(columns[4]), F = ErrorMessage(columns[5]), G = ErrorMessage(columns[6]), H = ErrorMessage(columns[7]), I = ErrorMessage(columns[8]) });


        myGridView.DataSource = data; 
        myGridView.DataBind();



<asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
    EnableModelValidation="True" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    Width="414px" align="center">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />

</asp:GridView>
```

So far, I have created a method which will change the text colour. Now, how can I implement this method? The text that should be changed red is the "No value entered!"

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve the problem!

```
using System.Drawing;

private string ErrorMessage(string input, int rowNr, int colNr)          
{             
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return input;

    myGridView.Rows[rowNr].Cells[colNr].ForeColor = Color.Red;
    return  "No value entered";
}
```

Another way is to add html tags like this...

```
using System.Drawing;

private string ErrorMessage(string input, int rowNr, int colNr)          
{             
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        return input;
    return  "<font color='Red'>" + "No value entered" + "</font>";
}
```

but I don't recommend the tags because `<font>` has been deprecated and you actually set the text value of the cell to html code.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

can you please explain this piece of code... mabe provide some context
what kind of syntax is this?

can you explain the .Select(...) commands how they work? what they do?

```
 // to read all lines of the posted csv file and put the lines in the grid view
        var data = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath(FilePath))
            // to split the lines according to commas
          .Select(line => line.Split(','))

          .Select(columns => new { A = ErrorMessage(columns[0]), B = ErrorMessage(columns[1]), C = ErrorMessage(columns[2]), D = ErrorMessage(columns[3]), E = ErrorMessage(columns[4]), F = ErrorMessage(columns[5]), G = ErrorMessage(columns[6]), H = ErrorMessage(columns[7]), I = ErrorMessage(columns[8]) });


        myGridView.DataSource = data; 
        myGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: It did not work when I used the method you gave me. It gives an error at my part which is the  = ErrorMessage(columns[0]), B = ErrorMessage(columns[1])... parts. If use HTML tags, it will display the whole thing, as in "<font color='Red'>" + "No value entered" + "</font>". Therefore, it is still not solved =/

Comment: did you correct the call's ? you need to call like this: ErrorMessage(columns[0], row number, column number) you have to specify the row and the column of the cell(text) you need to be red..